# vue beforeMount event is not working fine

Tags: vue.js

I read the documentation and as i know if i call functions in beforeMount it will execute in sequence.
and here is code which i don't know why it stoped working, it was working fine before as i expect to do it..

here is Code just posting that code which is relevent

```
 export default {
   data () {
      return { 
       all_months: [],
       selected_month:"",
     } //end return
   },//end data
 beforeMount(){
    if (localStorage.getItem('user') != null) {
        this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
        //console.log(this.user)
        this.register.parent_id = this.user.id
    }
    this.get_months(); 

    console.log('hello from beforeMount')
    console.log(this.selected_month)
    console.log(this.all_months)
    //this.proceed_date(this.all_months[0]);
 }, // end beforeMount
 mounted(){
    console.log('hello from Mount')
    console.log(this.selected_month)
 },
 methods: {
 get_months: function () {
        let api_token = this.user.api_token
        axios.get('api/get_months?api_token='+api_token)
        .then(response => {
            if('success'==response.data.status)
            {
                for (let i = 0 ; i <response.data.total; i++) {
                    this.all_months.push(response.data.all_months[i])
                } //for loop working fine
                console.log('hellor from get_months')
                console.log(this.all_months) //working fine
                this.selected_month = response.data.all_months[0] //working fine
                console.log(this.selected_month ) //working fine 
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            // this.snackbar_error = true
            // this.snackbar_text = err.response.data.message

        })
    }, //end get_months
 },//end methods
 }//end export
```

For now its working flow is like

in boforeMount this.get_months() function is called and it assign values to this.all_months and in get_months function is also assign value to this.selected_month and it print it in that function.
but when i access it in beforeMount event after calling this.get_months is gives empty string or undefined.

Before that it was working fine as expected i assgin values in get_months function and access it in beforeMount after get_months execution.

and that line which commented  //this.proceed_date(this.all_months[0]);  was also working fine.

**here is the console output flow for now.**

```
  hello from beforeMount 
  <empty string> 
  []
   0: "January 2019"
   1: "February 2019"
   2: "March 2019"
   3: "April 2019"
   4: "May 2019"
   5: "June 2019"
   6: "July 2019"
   7: "August 2019"
   8: "September 2019"
   9: "October 2019"
   10: "November 2019"
   11: "December 2019"
   12: "January 2020"
   13: "February 2020"
   14: "March 2020"
 __ob__: Object { value: (15) […], dep: {…}, vmCount: 0 }
 length: 15
  <prototype>: Object { … }
hello from Mount 
<empty string>
hellor from get_months 
 Array(15) [ "January 2019", "February 2019", "March 2019", "April 2019", "May 2019", "June 2019", "July 2019", "August 2019", "September 2019", "October 2019", … ]

January 2019
```

**Solutions I tried**

try to access this.selected_month in **mounted** event also but didn't work.

tried to find solutions from internet from 2  to 3 hours but unable to resolve it.

I'm very confuse how it was working fine before

Comment: Axios is a *Promise based HTTP client*, so you should take a look to how promises work https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: `this.get_months()` is called before `console.log('hello from beforeMount')` but in the output,`hello from beofreMount` is before `this.get_months()`'s output.I think because javascipt deals with async and sync function differently

Comment: but i was doing same thing before and it was running as expected. means first it calls this.get_months and assign values to  this.selected_month. but now it's doing reverse ... so i'm very confuse how it happend

Comment: @MuhammadAhtisham before what? post the code that was working. `get_months` run an asynchronous function so it's normal that `this.selected_month` in mounted is null

Comment: @fabruex that is same code and i'm also confuse how it was working fine before. maybe something changed in code and i do not remeber it.

Comment: But now I'm calling my next function where i have to use that this.selected_month in my this.get_months function. but it takes more time to response that is bad